# Undefined index when assigning value to array element

Tags: php, arrays

In while loop I'm assigning value pulled from DB to the array like so:

```
$states[$row['state']]
```

PHP gives me the following notice:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: ME in
>   /var/www/vhosts/basementfinishing-md-de.com/httpdocs/inc/class.cityBlock.php
>   on line 67

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try a `var_dump($states);` and see if there's any key called `'ME'` in the array. Or, `var_dump($row)` to make sure you're fetching the right data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `$row['state']` is 'ME' and this index is not defined for `$states`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough context to interpret the error message 100%, but I've been known to do something like this:

```
      $states = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($states, $row['state']);
      }
```